Django, how to get annotated field of related model
For example, the Invoice model has a project field that points a ForeignKey to the Project model, Project has a custom ProjectManager that has get_queryset defined, in get_queryset I do:
super().annotate(display=...)
and when I want to get this annotated field through Invoice:
Invoice.objects.filter(project__display__iregex=...)
then an error occurs that project does not have a display field, how can I make it so that the related models take fields from some queryset, this is get_queryset() for us

Django 4.2.4
Python 3.10

To take annotated fields I use Subquery:
Subquery(models.Project.objects.filter(id=OuterRef("project_id")).values_list("display"))

but because of this the request is executed very slowly.

You need to move on to update Django 5.0 and Python 3.12.5 or 3.14.0.

@toyotaSupra You seem to mean using ComputedField in Django 5, but is there an alternative as a library for Django 4?

When new Python 3. 12. Django 4 will not work. When the newer version will work, not, not the older version such as Python and Django.
